# What is the purpose of having two running ports when we working with ReactJS and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I just starting to learn MERN Stack development as a former .Net developer. I wanted to develop my skills in this area and after lots of researching I just can't figure it out why we need to have two different running port/app when we working with react js?

Firstly I have developed some simple application by using NodeJS, Express, EJS View Engine and already deploy it to Heroku. So far, this works fine for me. I can develop all my personel site with those technologies including MonoDb later. But to become complete MERN Stack developer I started to search React and realized that it only works with giving another port to seperate it like client application. Why we can't use react and all other things in under one port?

This confused me when I get two different web page under;
http://localhost:5000/ (React App)
http://localhost:3000/ (Server Side: opens different html given by me using EJS)

Apperantly if we give same port number with server (3000) in react's package.json file then it gives following warning;

Something is already running on port 3000.
npm run client exited with code 0

Is it due to nature of ReactJS?

Comment: `Why we can't use react and all other things in under one port?` you can! One thing you can do is when it's a `GET` request, you return react static files, and other requests go to your api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You totally can run `React` and `Node` on a single port - but it doesn't make for an efficient workflow.

**The core answer to your question lies in separating front-end routing from back-end routing.** 
When using `React Router` your application manages the UI based on the URL parameters.

i.e
`http://localhost:3000/some-ui-path`

At the same time when using `Node` as a back-end to respond to HTTP requests - you send the requests to specific URL paths.

i.e
`http://localhost:3000/some-api-path`

*Separating the ports easily lets you differentiate between which route should be handled by `React Router` on the front-end and which route should be directed to the `Node` on the back-end.*

`http://localhost:3000/some-ui-path` = React Route
`http://localhost:9000/some-api-path` = Node  HTTP Route

In your configuration files you can customize your front and back end setups so that any request to a certain path will be redirected to your node server.


**An Example:**
**you can define that any path prefixed with `/api/` should be proxied to port `9000`:**
`http://localhost:3000/api/some-api-path`  ==>  `http://localhost:9000/some-api-path`

You can use whichever ports you like but `3000` `5000` and `9000` are common defaults used by starter kits and module bundlers like `create-react-app` and `webpack`

Hope this helps, let me know if I can explain further!

Comment: This explains well some of the points in my mind, thank you for that. Besides those, I just curious, is it just for best-practice to seperate server and client application. I mean, in .NET I used to develop all parts in one module just by tracking MVC modelling. But in here it is new for me to run two different module application both for server and client.

Comment: Your welcome! Yes, it's definitely best practice to separate the your front and back ends - you'll really want to be able to debug code that runs on your server separately from code that runs on the client. Often times the client and server work in completely different runtimes based on who you choose to host your server with - and what browsers you are compiling for.  Separating them gives you the control to customize your server for one runtime and your client for another.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot run `React` and `Node.js` server in a single port.

**Why?**

> React uses `webpack` to bundle all the `component` files into a
>   `single` JS file. This JS file is then served by a
>   `webpack-dev-server` which is a part of `webpack`.

This `webpack-dev-server` is needed only during `development`. In `production`, you use `npm run build` or `yarn build` to bundle everything into a directory called `build` which will be served as a `static asset` by your `Node.js` server.

So, during `development`, you need to use two different ports for:

1. webpack-dev-server: This by default runs on `3000`. If you try to run your `Node.js` server, you'll get an error.
2. Node.js server: This should run on port other than `3000`.

Note: `webpack` is used as a default module bundler when creating React app using `create-react-app`.

Comment: `React` does not use `webpack` to bundle assets unless a developer chooses to implement it - or chooses a starter kit like `create-react-app`.

Comment: I'm talking about app created using 'create-react-app'

Comment: I have installed React using "create-react-app". So, it is caused by webpack thing just like you said then? And what happens to routing to that port after build? After all, isn't that still exist two module working on build environment for client and server? My main concern is that when we not use React we have one Node Module installed. But the point we decided to use React we suddenly needs another Node Module which needs to be run seperately by terminal. I don't get this point.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the port. `Port` is a logical construct that identifies a specific process or a type of network service. Port is a communication `endpoint`. And you have two different services, so it seems logical to use different ports generally. Your question is really good. I'm waiting for new answers.

Answer (score 0):

Also a .Net developer here! I had the exact same question around myself and [this article](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-serve-react-from-same-origin/) seems to clarify a little for me.

It seems like you need two servers (two ports) for development only. In production, you will only have an API server running, with some endpoints simply serving static files in `/build` directory like:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
})
```

I think the reason why we run two servers (one react webpack server and one API server) ports in development is because 1) we don't want to run `npm build` every time you make a change and 2) because of not needing to build every time you make changes, it allows hot-reloading for fast development.